# Should Citroen Ds3 Dstyle spare wheel question/s

Tags: citroen, spare-tire

I'm looking at a Citroen Ds3 Dstyle registered 2010, used at a second hand dealer. It does not have a spare wheel but looks like there should be one.

Are these easy and cheap to get and should I be concerned that there is not one with the car?

Answer (score 0):

No, many cars came with a "puncture get you home can" and still do.

You can source a spare wheel of the correct size as you wish.